# Magento Category 'parent_id' issue

Tags: magento

Can anyone please tell me whether the 'parent_id' for any root category is equal to 1?

```
array (size=10)
  'entity_id' => string '43' (length=2)
  'entity_type_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'attribute_set_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'created_at' => string '2014-12-23 05:43:06' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2014-12-23 05:43:06' (length=19)
  'path' => string '1/43' (length=4)
  'position' => string '3' (length=1)
  'level' => string '1' (length=1)
  'children_count' => string '0' (length=1)
```

parent_id = 1

Thank You

Comment: i fixed the issue. Root categories getting , root catalog 'entity_id' as the parent_id. So all the parent_id of root category under root catalog should be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue. Root categories getting , root catalog 'entity_id' as the parent_id. So all the parent_id of root category under root catalog should be same